# Laravel-str_random() can't generate unique random string for api_token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

i'm trying to generate a string for user's api_token in my database using `str_random(60)` and `unique()` function but looks like i'm doing it wrong. When i seed using `db:seed` two dummy users they should have different api_token(s). Here's my migration file

```
 $table->increments('id');
 $table->string('name');
 $table->string('email');
 $table->string('api_token')->default(str_random(60))->unique();
 $table->string('password');
 $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
 $table->timestamps();
```

If i remove the `unique()` function the users will have same api_token and if i put back that `unique()`, i will have an error because they will have same api_token. Can someone help me for this unique api_token case, please?

Comment: are you running `db:seed` two times or just once while keeping this code in a loop?

Comment: You need to set the token in seeder or factory, not in migration.

Comment: You can use `Str::Random` which is laravel's `illuminate` and according to it's phpdoc it `Generate a more truly "random" alpha-numeric string.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `default()` with `unique()`. Because `default()` is a value which is set to a row when there isn't any value put in this column. So you shouldn't use both together.

Change it to:

```
$table->string('api_token')->unique();
```

And

> You must set the api_token in seeder, not in migration.